# How to add the target jar as a test resource of the same project?

Tags: testing, compiler-construction, maven, solr, dependency-management

I'm developing a [Solr plugin](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPlugins#How_to_Load_Plugins) and using the [Solr test-framework](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2061) I place a test `SOLR_HOME` dir under `test/resources` with `/conf/` and `/lib` . Now the framework inistantiates a `SolrCore` and loads my plugin from `/lib`. Not an issue to output the jar of the plugin to `/lib`, but the issue is that the plugin is not yet available since it still needs to past the test (chicken and the egg).

How do you recommend solving this? I see those options:

1. **Create another project for the tests** with a dependency on the plugin, and in it run the tests. Simple enough, but how do I ensure that everytime the plugin is built also the tests of this other project is built? The point of the automated tests at every build is to having a new plugin jar which breaks the tests.
2. In [dp4j pom.xml](http://code.google.com/p/dp4j/source/browse/pom.xml) I **build the project on 2 phases**, in the 1st I `<include>` only the annotation processors while in the other I compile the tests which rely on the annotation processors compiled in the eariler phase.

I'm in favor of 2 since copy-pasting the configuration doesn't seem a bad option, and makes it seem less complicated than it probably is. I don't remember if I had asked about it here - what do you recommend? Any other case studies /working code to look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's a 3rd. most probably best solution ~ do nothing!
I was under the impression that the Solr Testframework need to load my plugin from  `/lib` but apparently it doesn't need to, it can load it from `test-classes`, all on its own!